# Assign dataframe to array

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I want to divide the time series into one dataframe per year, and further compute sum, max, time of max etc....
Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
year=[2016,2017,2018,2019,2020]
start=[""]*5
end=[""]*5
for i in range(5):
    start[i] = str(year[i])+"-01-01 00:00:00"
    end[i] = str(year[i]+1)+"-01-01 00:00:00"

period0 = df.loc[(df.Time_series >= start[0]) & (df.Time_series < end[0])]
period1 = df.loc[(df.Time_series >= start[1]) & (df.Time_series < end[1])]
period2 = df.loc[(df.Time_series >= start[2]) & (df.Time_series < end[2])]
period3 = df.loc[(df.Time_series >= start[3]) & (df.Time_series < end[3])]
period4 = df.loc[(df.Time_series >= start[4]) & (df.Time_series < end[4])]

#Any suggestions on how to assign the dataframe to an array, like this?:
period[i] = df.loc[(df.Time_series >= start[i]) & (df.Time_series < end[i])]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting with the current code? Can you share an example `df` and the expected output

Comment: "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" Probably because the array isen't declared in the right way. The expected output is the 'Time series' in the first column and measure data in the next 75 columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.